# Redirect output from JNI library

Tags: android, java-native-interface

I'm looking for a way to redirect/capture the stdout output of a native library in a simple Android app.  I've seen a couple posts on this but I'm not finding the answers to my questions.

As much as possible I'd like to avoid tinkering with the existing native library.  My first impulse is to use a fifo file and redirect the native library's output.  I can't seem to get past the call to Runtime.getRuntime().exec("mkfifo(,0666)").  I'm trying to create the file in /data/data/ but the file doesn't seem to exist after the program runs.  I also can't seem to find 'mkfifo' in the Android filesystem (via adb shell).

Couple of dumb questions:
- Where is mkfifo?
- Should I be able to see the fifo file after the program runs or is there a more reliable way to test the fifo's existence from Java after I run the above command?
- Is there another/better approach to take for this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to redirect it specifically to a file? Then what you probably wanna do is:

```
int fd = open(filename, "w");
dup2(fd, 1);
close(fd);
```

I have no idea how will this affect the Java subsystem.

Also note that the `/data/data` might not be writable. The application sandbox is under `/data/data/com.mypackage/`, and Android expects you to create subdirectories for your data there via `Context.getDir()`. `/sdcard` is always writable, but you have to check availability first - the card is by definition removable storage.

If redirecting to a file is not your ultimate desire, then `pipe()` might be a better choice. `dup2()` the write end to 1, and read from the read end, preferably in a different thread. Then it's up to you what to do to the data read.

Comment: I'd actually like to avoid having to create a file at all. I thought using a FIFO or pipe still requires the creation of file in the underlying filesystem. Ideally I'd like to create an Input Stream in java, pass it to the native library and just add some minimal code there to dup() stdout out to that stream.  From what I've been able to find, this doesn't appear to be a kosher approach. My call to mkfifo is in the package directory as you indicated.  I've read that FAT32 filesystem on /sdcard doesn't support fifo filetypes. I'll look further into using a simple pipe. Any idea where mkfifo is?

Comment: I agree that getting the filesystem involved is not a good idea. A pipe, however, is not backed by the filesystem. It's just two file handles where what goes into one comes out of the other. You cannot, however, construct a Java InputStream over a raw handle value (which is an `int`). Maybe you can get the file handle value (via reflection in JNI) for a Java pipe object (`java.nio.Pipe`)...

Comment: So what I'm saying, the cleanest way is to create a pipe in the native code, read from the read end in the native code as well, and pass the data back to Java as byte arrays.

Comment: I was basically dead in the water as "mkfifo" doesn't seem to exist in the Android root file system so any call to Runtime.exec() from Java was doing nothing.  I added code to the native library to run mkfifo() and I'm able to create a file now in the aforementioned directory.  If I can reroute stdio of the native library to this FIFO I should be getting close.  Thanks a lot for you help.

Answer (score 0):

It's very easy in your case:

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
InputStream processOut = process.getInputStream();
InputStream processError = process.getErrorStream();
```

But I can't find the solution for myself. I have java library that puts its content into a file (identified by `String fileName` or `FileDescriptor fd`). Also there is a native library. I need to redirect output from the first one to input of the second library. I thought that fifo is a solution, but **android file system is fat32 and can't have FIFO files**.